# Is there any convention regarding how to represent a Map?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I understand that [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) (and [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)) doesn't have a literal notation, that's not my question. My question is, *precisely because* it doesn't have a literal notation, how do I write it down?

For instance, if I had this object:

```
+-----+-------------+
| key |    value    |
+-----+-------------+
| foo | 42          |
| bar | hello world |
+-----+-------------+
```

I'd write it down as:

```
obj = {
    foo: 42,
    bar: "hello world"
}
```

But if I had the same thing as a Map...

```
+-----+-------------+
| key |    value    |
+-----+-------------+
| foo | 42          |
| bar | hello world |
+-----+-------------+
```

How would I write it down? Is there any accepted convention for representing a Map?

Comment: Types matter. A key of `1` is not the same as a key of `'1'` in a Map, so to distinguish, I'd use Javascript syntax, perhaps in the form of the array the Map constructor receives.

Comment: @CertainPerformance how would that look like?

Comment: No convention but usually arrows are used. But you might get `key => value` or `key -> value`, so it's not even consistent. Just represent it in whatever way that makes sense - that's what all other tools are doing, anyway.

Comment: `"foo" => 42` is how the chrome browser console displays it. But, there is way to *represent* it if the key is an object.

Comment: A simple answer is that _there is no standard convention_ to represent a map. You can devise your own approach and remain consistent on it throughout the examples in usage. This question is primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @adiga Firefox uses a single line arrow. In fact, it uses the symbol `→`. So, no real convention for arrows.

Comment: It's interesting that people voted to close this as *opinion-based*. One possible answer is *"there is no convention for representing a Map"*. That's clearly **not** opinion-based, that's a stated fact. On the other hand, how someone will represent his/her Map, supposing that indeed there is no convention, would be a matter of choice. But the fact that the representation per se is a matter of choice doesn't make this present question *opinion-based*, since the actual answer (again, supposing that there is no convention) would **not** be opinion-based!

Comment: The question is *how* you write it down. Since it's up to each individual, it's opinion based. Otherwise every opinion-based question e.g., "should I avoid using the letter `z` in my variable?" would have a canonical answer of "there is no answer" which is not very useful.

Answer (score -3):

You can define it using list of entries:

```js
new Map([
  [ 'foo', 42 ],
  [ 'bar', 'hello world' ]
])
```

Or from object:

```js
new Map(Object.entries({ foo: 42, bar: 'hello world' }));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I know hot to create a Map. That's not the question.

Answer (score -3):

**No, there is no standard for a literal notation, like for arrays or objects.**

Instead, you could take the same structure for generating a map as a data structure for a persist storrage.

```js
var map = new Map([["foo", 42], ["bar", "hello world"]]),
    data = Array.from(map);

console.log(data);
```

Comment: That's interesting, but if I write this down in a piece of paper or online it's indistinguishable from a common array of arrays. Don't you agree?

Comment: right. but this is the only format, which is interchangeable.